# Accessing parent class field "this.field" VS "super.field"

Tags: java, inheritance, field

I want to know the difference between accessing parent class fields using `this` and `super`.

We have the following abstract class named ListItem which extends Node class.

```
public abstract class ListItem {
        protected ListItem rightLink=null;
        abstract ListItem next();
    }
```

And the following code inside the Node class:

```
public class Node extends ListItem {
@Override
    ListItem next() {
        return this.rightLink;
    }
```

But if we use the code super.rightLink, I do not get any error at compile time or runtime. I just want to know what is the difference between the both and is there a best practice to accomplish the task?

Answer (score 9):

### Explanation

It does not matter **in this case**, there is no difference.

The field is declared in the parent class. So technically `super.rightLink` would makes the most sense. However, `super` and `this` are only relevant for resolving *ambiguous* situations with variable shadowing.

The best in this case would be to leave out any prefix and just type `rightLink`. But this is a bit opinion-based.

---

### Example

Suppose we have the following

```
public class Parent {
    int variable = 1; // Field
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    int variable = 2; // Field

    public void foo() {
        int variable = 3; // Local variable

        System.out.println(variable); // 3
        System.out.println(this.variable); // 2
        System.out.println(super.variable); // 1
    }
}
```

---

### In-depth

So we have a situation with 3 different variables which all live in a different scope, but they have the same name. When you just type `variable`, Java will refer to the variable with the lowest scope. Which would be the local variable in the method.
If you want to access your field, you need to do `this.variable`. If you want to access the field of your parent, you need to do `super.variable`.

So again, we have three different variables here.

- *no prefix*: lowest scope
- `this`: field with lowest scope
- `super`: field with lowest scope, starting from the direct parent

In your specific example, however, we have no name shadowing at all. There is only one variable with the name `rightLink`. So all three variants refer to the exact same variable.

The best in this case would be to use no prefix at all, just `rightLink`.

---

### JLS

Let us see how the Java Language Specification defines `this.` and `super.`.

For `this.`, refer to [JLS§15.8.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3):

> When used as a primary expression, the keyword `this` denotes a value that is a **reference to the object** for which the instance method or default method was invoked ([§15.12](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12)), or to the object being constructed. The value denoted by this in a lambda body is the same as the value denoted by this in the surrounding context.

For `super.`, refer to [JLS§15.11.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.2):

> The form `super.Identifier` refers to the field named `Identifier` of the current object, but with the **current** object **viewed as an instance** of the **superclass** of the current class.

Answer (score 1):

Unless `rightLink` is marked as private, it will be accessible in all classes deriving from `ListItem`. Thus, call `super.rightLing` and `this.rightLink` will be equivalent.

Generally, `super` refers to base class and `this` refers to class you are in. Use them appropraitely.

It's commonly used when overriding methods, i.e.

```
@Override
public void DoSomething(){
  // Execute base imlpementation of a method
  super.DoSomething();
  // some additional code to add extra functionality to base class
}
```